# Is relocation assistance offered to postdocs?

Tags: postdocs, negotiation, contract

Do universities offer relocation assistance to a newly employed postdoc who comes from another country? Is it appropriate for the postdoc to ask for relocation assistance if it is not already offered?

Comment: You can ask; in my experience (UK), the answer will be no.

Comment: Are you talking about something financial (which I have not heard of yet), or about help with finding a place to stay and university-internal offers of temporary locations for the newly-arrived before they have found a permanent place to rent (which is pretty much standard in some places)?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I think your comment can be written as an answer.

Comment: @adipro: I'd be wary of that, as on the one hand, I'm asking for clarification of the question, and on the other hand, I cannot provide any more than anecdotal evidence from the few places that I have contact to.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It varies. In my experience some of the more prestigious postdoctoral fellowships sponsored by universities might have some amount of moving expenses built into the budget, and more typical postdoc positions funded out of grants probably won't. But it might be possible to get a professor to help you out, perhaps out of startup or some other funds that aren't earmarked for a particular purpose. You should try to negotiate it with the person who offers you the job *before* you accept the offer.

Comment: I think this is right, but be careful in negotiating and offer. Make sure the amount of assistance you are asking for is reasonable.

Comment: You highlighted the word **before**; does that mean that it is too late to ask after one accepts the offer? For example, how if, after one moves to the country, temporary accommodation turns out to be much more expensive than first estimated?

Comment: @adipro: You could certainly ask, but after you have accepted the offer you have no leverage.  They have no real incentive to give it to you, other than just to be nice.

Comment: On two occasions my PI started my pay a week or two before I actually arrived to start work, but that was as good as it got.

Answer (score 6):

In disciplines that I'm familiar with, postdoc money comes from a grant obtained by a PI. So the university has little-to-no role in the hiring and compensation process. I imagine the postdoc would have to discuss this issue with the PI.

Answer (score 6):

In the early 90's, when I did a postdoc for a U.S. National Laboratory, full relocation expenses were included, which involved moving my household clear across the country, and staying in a hotel for a bit at the other end while I looked for a new home. I doubt such generous deals are readily available today.

Comment: These days, the National Labs still offer good deals to postdocs compared to the universities, but they're more likely to offer to pay airfare/reimburse driving costs, and also supply a fixed sign-on bonus. Depending on distance and living conditions, that may cover part or all of the expenses.

Comment: At the US National Lab I work at, we definitely pay relocation for post-docs. It may be capped, but moving, temporary housing, etc. are covered.

Answer (score 4):

In the Netherlands, relocation reimbursement for post-docs, both a lump sum and a refund for transporting your possessions, is *mandated* by the collective employment agreements. For the non-university research institutes, [Chapter 10 of the the 2018 CAO agreement](https://www.wvoi.nl/media/1154/chapter-10-2018.pdf) spells this out. The amount is about 2,000 EUR for a fixed-term employment contract.

I have no experience elsewhere, (un?)fortunately.

Comment: Almost 30 years ago I bought a plane ticket to Amsterdam from the US, threw what I could carry into my backpack, and headed out. No relocation. Times were different...

Comment: @JonCuster: I'm assuming you had no apartment? Almost no clothes? No books? No computer? etc. :-(

Comment: The institute arranged a room to rent. But, yes, I took almost nothing with me.

Answer (score 3):

Some Australian universities offer very generous relocation packages as a matter of institutional policy.  Most other places do not seem to offer it, but it is definitely okay to ask.